# video: bytes escritos en fichero son diferentes de los que se leen

Tags: laravel

soy nuevo con opencv y tengo una duda. Lo explico usando el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def LoadVideo(fileName):
    # Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
    # If the input is taken from the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name.
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fileName)
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()        
        if ret == True:        
            # Display the resulting frame
            cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
            frame2 = np.array(frame)
                    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break        
        # Break the loop
        else: 
            break

    # When everything done, release the video capture object
    cap.release()

    # Closes all the frames
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def WriteVideo(fileName):
    encoding = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('I','4','2','0')
    #encoding = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('8','B','P','S')
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName, encoding, 2, (300,300))
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName, 0, 2, (300,300))
    ret = video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB,1)
    nFrames = 30
    for i in range(nFrames):
        frame = np.multiply(np.ones((300,300,3),dtype=np.uint8),i)
        video.write(frame)
    video.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WriteVideo('hola.avi')
    LoadVideo('hola.avi')
```

El programa simplemente escribe imágenes usando matrices de 300x300x3 que en la primera frame son todos los valores 0, en la segunda todos son 1, etc.

Lo que yo esperaba es que al leer (y decodificar) el video con read es encontrarme las mismas matrices, pero resultan que no son las que escribí (están codificadas de alguna forma).

la pregunta es si hay forma de recuperar la información original.

Comment: ¿Laravel? ¿Seguro?